# RSA private key included in JWT token

Tags: jwt

Could someone kindly explain why the private key is included (by default) in the JWT-Token generated by "all" the cpp-based JWT libraries found on github & how to remove it?

Comment: I doubt that. Please demonstrate it.

Comment: Its turns out, I was wrong. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that comes close is the signature of the JWT (the last part in blue at the example in https://jwt.io/).

You need the private key to *calculate* the signature, but it is definitely not included in the JWT!

Comment: Thanks for the response to and the correction of my question.

My confusion however remains the fact, that when I paste the token - generated using the library - on jwt.io, the private key is also included. E.g:

eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6IiIsImV4cCI6IjE1ODU4MzU2NTMiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkc2Zkc2FmZmpqZCIsImlhdCI6IjE1ODU4MzU2NTIiLCJpc3MiOiJhdXRoMiIsInN1YiI6IkFudGlHaG9zdFdvcmtlcnwxIn0.c_zLVRNISlufxPHFr_zteNvY1BG3Yvjm6oFf6-ZPS9Z3rlr4NcGNLX6GGTlWVVRGjwSi3xim9t1wqwe3xhCcbwMbL2s9spNa24nFf10njtJHR1v-CsQmnsp2zVY5DpDdRn1gX1gF5iVVqgrPLjk_aiY6SwV5Rf6gpCqTM_s23lU

Btw, Algo:RS256

Comment: When I copy-paste your JWT into the site, I see two boxes: one that asks for a public key if I want to _verify_ the signature, and one that asks for a private key if I want to _make_ a signature. Again, how do you infer from that that the private key "is also included"? Perhaps jwt.io caches some state for you?

Comment: My bad... Turns out, the keys in those boxes are the ones generated by jwt.io ...

Thanks!

Comment: I just ran into the same puzzling scenario. How did you find out that they're generated by jwt.io?

Comment: Presumably because the boxes were filled in instead of left empty.